# What is RAM balooning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, memory-management, shared-memory, ram

I came to this question on quora. "Does AWS use RAM ballooning or not?".

Searched on google, but unable to clearly / completely understand.
(Added this line after reading comments. I don't know much about virtual machine. Thus may be I haven't understood this concept to the fullest extent.).

If anybody can explain with examples or give a link (if possible with pictures / videos).

Comment: First hit: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/30466/memory-ballooning

Comment: Where have you already looked? And ideally if there is a specific thing you can point out in those places, what did you not understand?